# Google Analytics Tracking Conversions with vendor data and custom campaigns

Tags: google-analytics

Please help me understand this. I have a client for whom we created a sweepstakes "mini site". Traffic was generated through banner ads, eBlasts, and newsletters. For the banner ads, I created custom urls, i.e. www.somewhere.com?utm_source=yahoo?utm_campaign=abc to track the traffic to the landing page per vendor/banner. this works just fine.

The entrant visits the page, signs up for the sweepstakes, has as double opt in email process for verification. All of my entering traffic to the landing page is tracking fine, and is properly broken down by utm_source and utm_campaign.

Some of the vendors had me place tracking pixels on the confirmation page for conversion statistics. The only info I have placed for internal tracking on the confirmation page is the GA tracking code.

I have been told to create tracking pixels to track the individual vendor conversions. Is this possible without the originating pixel data from the vendor? I am new to tracking pixels, but my understanding is that I need some information from the vendor in order to write the code for the pixel. Am I wrong?

I can't understand how we can place a tracking pixel on our end without at least campaign name or data from the vendor's tracking pixel that they placed on the page containing our banner ads.

What am I missing here? How can I actually separate the conversion traffic from the different sources when everyone receives the same double-opt-in email?

Please ask me to clarify if I am not being clear. Thanks in advance for reading my question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you are trying to track here.  One is Campaigns: Campaigns are how you measure the effectiveness of techniques to *bring* users to your site.

The *other* thing you are tracking is Events - this is what users are doing once they arrive at your site.  If you want to track individual vendor conversions, you should add an onclick handler to either the submit button, or link that you are calling a "conversion"

For example:

```
<a href="http:/mywebsite.com/checkout" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Category', 'Action', 'Label']);">Your link here</a>
```

If you are adding the push to a form submit, you might want to have that push happen on the pageload of the success page, rather than the onClick of the submit (otherwise it will track the event, and it might not have actually happened due to form validation errors for example)